# How does single coax wire transmit a lot of information?

Tags: transmission-line, digital-communications, coax

I have a coax cable entering my house.  The cable (from the Cable company), splits into a Cable modem (for computer network) and into a DVR (a.k.a. cable box).

How can a single coax wire contain digital programming information for over 100 channels and transmit data to the internet at fast speeds?

For example, my DVR box can record multiple channels while my PC is transmitting to and from the internet (via the cable).

I'm familiar with interfaces that use one bit per wire (such as Centronics Parallel) or send bit pulses using more than one wire (I2C, RS232C, USB, Ethernet).  These transmission forms are not as fast as the coax.

Comment: It is not an issue to explain with a diagram, you have to grasp the concept of bandwidth of a transmission media. Also you have to understand the building of a network. When the coax reaches your home it is the final connection of a network that usually has a fiber backbone. Think also that you could ask a similar question about the AIR, which "transports" hundreds of TV channels.

Comment: Radio, TV, data, etc are carried wirelessly via the same medium. Why should a copper wire be any different in principle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of prior research.

Comment: Broadcast TV uses different frequencies to transmit the data.  Is this true of Coax/Cable?  Are there reserved frequency ranges?

Comment: I2C, RS232 and USB are all direct-digital. They don't use complex modulation to take full advantage of the cable because they are meant to be cheap and short-distance. Ethernet is more complex but still not the most. State-of-the-art modulation can do over 100bit/Hz and even some cheap cable can do well above 100MHZ passband.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for a "30,000 foot view" answer, right?  That is, a general answer w/o any particulars?

The new game is "how much digital data can I send through a cable?".  Once digital data transmission is achieved, then anything can be [DIGITIZED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitization), [COMPRESSED](http://digital%20compressoin) and [MULTIPLEXED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing) into the data stream.

To send digital data over coax, any number and combination of analog techniques can be used.  For instance, an [amplitude change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation) of an analog sine wave can indicate the difference between 0s and 1s.  The same can be said for a [change in phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_modulation) of the same sine wave.  If combined these two modulation techniques are called [QAM encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation).  If not enough, we can take another step and transmit many such signals over the same coax cable by using [sine waves of different frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-division_multiplexing). There are more analog techniques that may or may not be suitable for transmission over coax.

Most if not all forms of communications you use in a day is actually DIGITIZED at some point.  Phone calls, cable TV and iPods are examples where the media is likely digitized at some point.

Most data people use is highly redundant.  Music, speech and motion pictures are three examples where COMPRESSION can reduce the amount of data to transmit by an order of magnitude or more.

MULTIPLEXING data in the digital domain can be done any number of ways.  But in general, digital data is broken up into small groups of numbers which can be transmitted each in turn.  This is usually referred to as [time division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing).

These and more clever techniques are likely employed to deliver the broad range of media to your home over that coax wire entering your house.

Comment: Don't read more into your cable company's offerings then there really are.  For instance, it might be that there are only a few dozen channels of bandwidth available between you and your neighbors.  But there are over 100 channels to choose from.  But at any time you and your neighbors might only be streaming a dozen unique channels.  See what I mean by "clever techniques"?  Once you digitize, compress and multiplex your data, there are many new options to optimize performance.

Comment: Is there room in this brief overview summary to mention [frequency-division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/frequency-division_multiplexing) ?

Comment: Sure @davidcary, why not.  But let's not push it too far, I never could handle stuff like spread spectrum and frequency hopping :).